# Convert physical centos to VHD

Tags: linux, centos, hyper-v, vhd

Is there any software to convert physical machine with centOS operationg system to VHD image?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Boot WinPE from a CD and run disk2vhd.

I'm also told that there are VHD conversion tools from the Xen camp.  And those may be easier to deploy across CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your goal is a P2V conversion? I had good results with Citrix XenConvert. But I did not target Hyper-V.

http://citrix.com/English/ss/downloads/details.asp?downloadId=2318170&productId=683148